# R package for marketing

Tags: r, marketing

I'm taking an intro to marketing class this semester and the course requires us to buy a software which looks nothing more than a bunch of excel macros. From the [software's page](http://www.decisionpro.biz/products/marketing-engineering-for-excel)

> Marketing Engineering for Excel provides tools to help address the most common marketing problems Segmentation, Targeting and Positioning (STP); New Product Decision; Sales Forecasting; Advertising and Communication Decisions; Salesforce and Channel Decisions; Pricing; and Sales Promotion Decisions. Users will be able to harness the power of world-class analytics to run quick and simple analyses... all from within Excel.

I'll buy the license for the software (40 bucks for 6 months)... but can anyone tell me if there are R packages that do similar stuff?

Comment: All of these can be done in R, however, there is not just one package that covers everything and it certainly won't be a click and win situation. It will be less automated.

Comment: It will be less automated out of the gate.  Once you know R better your ability to analyze will be more automated.

Comment: Great to know that these can be done in R ... Interesting that there is not a single package. Sounds  like a great opportunity to get started into hacking r packages. :)

Comment: Forgive me my ignorance of the depths of decision marketing, but such a package might only mask other packages. You might consider to create a view instead (http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/) which collects packages per purpose and then create a package for all functions you have missed :).

Comment: How do I go about creating a view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One clarifying question would be: how familiar are you with R already?

To be honest, not buying the macros is probably too risky. Will the teacher expect your assignments to exactly match the results of the macros? Might they even expect you to submit Excel spreadsheets as your answers? Are the techniques used in the macros straight out of your textbook (i.e. you could reproduce them in R) or are you going to have to reverse engineer what the macros do (without having them in hand) to duplicate the results in R? If you need help, will the teacher, teaching assistants, classmates only be able to speak in terms of Excel?

I used R in a machine learning class where the teacher highly recommended Matlab, and I was the only one who used R. (I think one or two folks used Java, maybe one Python.) I'd been working in R for years, though, and was quite confident I could do what needed to be done, even though I could not use the recommended Matlab Toolkits. I did well in the class, but you really have to have your eyes open going in and feel comfortable in R and in finding the right R packages to accomplish what you need to do.

If you buy the macros, you can still try to replicate the results in R. (Check your results against the macros.) That way, you'll be preparing for the future. Your situation is sort of like where the professor requires you to buy their book for the course: sometimes it's easier to pay the ransom than to fight.

Comment: +1, been there, done that. Explaining why R does things in certain ways compared to other software can add significant time and burden to the class that you may not otherwise account for(i.e. reference levels for factors, etc)...or just simply getting data into the right format can be a challenge.

Comment: I ended up using the excel addon as it would have been too much work to replicate so much in R. The course and the text book was designed around the software - so what the Professor expected would not have been reproducible.

Comment: I'd recommend that if you are an R user you at least make a stab -- after you've done it using Excel and the addon -- at reproducing at least some of your results in R. You'd really understand it after that. (But you may not have the time, of course.) Obviously, turn in the answers from Excel, so that the professor sees what he/she expects.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this open source project:

https://github.com/lukaszdz/library

It contains implementations of the most commonly used probability distributions in Marketing. It should cover the sales forecasting and adoption models of the package you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of R is its flexibility - a good place to start with business data is this list of R packages by task http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ - in particular, you'll find lists for Econometrics, Social Science, Optimization, Time Series (Forecasting) and others. Here is a great case study application of R for campaign forecasting http://www.inside-r.org/howto/direct-marketing-flight-forecasting-system.